# Defining immersions and submersions of manifolds in locally ringed spaces.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the usual notions of ringed spaces in the setting of manifolds and vice versa.

Recall the definitions of open and closed immersions:

> A morphism $f:X\to Y$ of locally ringed spaces is an *open immersion* if the underlying continuous map is a homeomorphism of $X$ onto an open subset $U$ of $Y$ such that the sheaf map $\mathscr{O}_Y\to f_*\mathscr{O}_X$ restricts to an isomorphism over $U$.

> A morphism $f:X\to Y$ of locally ringed spaces is a *closed immersion* if the underlying continuous map is a homeomorphism of $X$ onto a closed subset of $Y$ such that the sheaf map $\mathscr{O}_Y\to f_*\mathscr{O}_X$ is surjective.

If $X$ and $Y$ are (smooth) manifolds, I think that open / closed immersions are simply smooth morphisms whose image is open / closed in $Y$ and that restrict to diffeomorphisms on their images. (Please correct me if I'm wrong!)

More generally,

> A morphism $f:X\to Y$ of locally ringed spaces is an *immersion* if the underlying continuous map is a homeomorphism of $X$ onto a locally closed subset $U$ of $Y$ such that for all $p\in X$ the stalk map $\mathscr{O}_{Y,f(p)}\to \mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ is surjective.

I have two questions then:

1. Is that the same thing as an embedding of manifolds? That is, a smooth map that is both a topological embedding and an immersion (not in the sense above but in the usual manifold sense).
2. Can we describe immersions and submersions (in the usual manifold sense) in a similar fashion?

Comment: Look in Wedhorn's sheaves, manifolds, and cohomology for the answer.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I did! He talks about immersions and submersions in the usual way (using differentials) and, while theorem 5.34 is somewhat close to my first question, it does not answer it.

Comment: How does it not answer your question??

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ is an embedding, then $f$ is indeed a homeomorphism of $X$ onto a locally closed subset $S$ of $Y$. Also $f:X\to S$ is a diffeomorphism, which implies that $f^\flat:f^{-1}\mathscr{O}_S\to \mathscr{O}_X$ is an isomorphism of sheaves. In particular, the stalk map is surjective. But what about the converse? Theorem 5.34 does not talk about that at all.

Comment: Actually, now I'm not even sure that the stalk map is surjective. Indeed $\mathscr{O}_{S,f(p)}\to \mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ is an isomorphism. But does $\mathscr{O}_{Y,f(p)}\to\mathscr{O}_{X,p}$ needs to be surjective?